# setOnTouchListener not works on FrameLayout

Tags: android

I have layout wich has FrameLayout which internally has some views. i want to listen the touch event on FrameLayout. i tried by setting the setOnTouchListener on FrameLayout but it seems it doesnt work.

I went through ViewGroup docs, in ViewGroup there is method called onInterceptTouchEvent() which used to intercept the touch event.

In mycase how can i override the onInterceptTouchEvent() ? since my FrameLayout is defined in xml and i dont have any custom view group.

any idea about how to do ?

Thanks !

Comment: Provide your code snippet so we can help...

Answer (score -1):

I added OnClickListener on LinearLayout before， it work well, you can have a try.